# Incorrect syntax near '=' on INSERT INTO SQL Server statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql

The following code throws the error mentioned in the title, I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. The table is created using Entity Framework and the columns are of type `INT` which the sent parameters are.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StudentCourse VALUES (StudentID=@StudentID, CourseID=@CourseID)", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseID", courseID);

    conn.Open();
    int test = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (test > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Table updated!");
}
```

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StudentCourse(StudentID,CourseID) VALUES (@StudentID, @CourseID)", conn);

Comment: You are mixing property assignment with column value assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write like this

```
INSERT INTO StudentCourse (StudentID, CourseID) VALUES(@StudentID, @CourseID)
```

This is the way the SQL insert works.

Comment: Yes i will, still gotta wait 5 mins before I'm allowed to